# Partitioning edges/diagonals in subsets of three, originating from the same vertex

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Clearer version:
Is it possitle to partition the set of edges and diagonals of a 100-gon in subsets of three elements, originating from the same vertex?

---

I was wondering if there would be a simple way to know if for a n-gon, when inspecting its edges and diagonals, there is a way to color three edge/diagonals from each vertex with unique colors. For example, for a triangle there doesn't exist three edge/diagonals from a vertex, so the answer is impossible. For a square, it's also impossible because if you take three edge/diagonals from one vertex, then you can't get the remaining three lines to meet at another vertex. In a similar sense, a hexagon seems to work.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Math.SE! Can you elaborate your point about the square? It seems to me that if you color two opposite edges in red, the remaining edges in blue and the diagonals in green you would obtain the desired coloring. By the way, you may find useful information here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_coloring

Comment: I meant that we want to color exactly three sides/diagonals originating from the same vertex. For the case of the square, if we color the two sides and the diagonal originating from the top left vertex, then there is no way to map the remaining two sides and one diagonal to one vertex.

Comment: Ok, so you would like to know if you can partition the set of edges and diagonals in subsets of three elements, originating from the same vertex. Is that right?

Comment: Yup, this question just popped up in my head, so it was hard getting it down into words. Thanks

Comment: Great! I think that editing your post to state the problem in a clearer way might help you in getting some attention! Changing the title and adding some other tags might also help you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the partition can be done for $6n$, then it can be done for $6n+6$. Take a partition of the edge/diagonals of $K_{6n}$ and enhance it by adding the following: for each new vertex divide the edges going out of it to the $6n$ vertices of $K_{6n}$ into groups of 3. For the 15 edge/diagonals among the 6 new vertices, use the partition of $K_6$.

It follows that the partition exists for $K_{6n}$ by induction (since it exists for $K_6$. But then it exists for $K_{6n+1}$ as well. Simply partition the new edge/diagonals coming out of the additional vertex into the other 6n vertices in groups of 3.

It is not possible for $K_{6n+2}$ since the number of edge/diagonals is $(6n+2)(6n+1)/2$ which is not divisible by 3. Similarly it is not possible for $K_{6n+5}$.

The only cases remaining are $K_{6n+3}$ and $K_{6n+4}$. Note that again $K_{6n+4}$ follows from $K_{6n+3}$. For $K_{6n+3}$, we show the partition exists for $n\geq 1$. Take the partition for $k_{6n}$ and enhance it as follows. Choose one from the $6n$ vertices and connect it to the 3 new vertices. Then divide each of the remaining $6n+1$ edge/diagonals coming out of the 3 vertices into groups of 3 by including only 1 of the edge/diagonals connecting to the other three vertices.